Seeking recommendations for a set of טור ושולחן ערוך
I am seeking recommendations for a set of טור ושולחן ערוך. (A set “in progress” is worthwhile for consideration too — I mostly learn אורח חיים and יורה דעה so I’m not really needing a full set anyway other than that I’m mentally pre-programmed to want complete sets.)
For years I used an old set of טור and an old set of שולחן ערוך from my father, a”h, which were published in the early 1980s (or maybe late 1970s? I’m going off memory here). Both sets are sitting in storage back in the USA (I’m based in London, England now).
I’ve mostly been using digital text libraries for the last four years and am less up to date with published options. There are also not many well-stocked ספרים shops near me, so I’ve not had a chance to thumb through more recent options either.
I’d really like to get back into using actual published books — especially as my children are now getting closer to an age where I can learn with them on Shabbos.
My preferences are

clarity and corrected text are my primary considerations
I’d prefer fewer ראשי תיבות to make life easier but this is nice to have and not essential
Tzuras Hadaf is also nice enough but not a real consideration either way
I’m not concerned about pricing per se

In making recommendations, please include your reasoning. Thank you.

We had this question for SA before, see Buying a Shulchan Aruch

Thanks, yes I saw that but as the question was seemingly posed some years ago, I thought it made sense to ask independently. Also I thought the combined טור ושולחן ערוך focus was distinct enough. Oh, also I’m not concerned about pricing per se.

also relevant: Difference between two sets of the Tur

There are quite a few nice sets now available that are worth exploring.

The Tzuras HaDaf - Tur Shulchan Aruch: Like the name suggests it is formatted and paginated with the traditional tzuras hadaf layout, but the text is nice and clear and a good primer in how to "read" the development of halacha.

Tur Shulchan Aruch Habahir - Also very nice. Has lot of purchase options if you don't want to spend so much at once - i.e. you can buy just the Orach Chaim section as well as having multiple sizes.

There is also the Tur Shulchan Aruch Hamaor, but I have not seen it properly to provide enough information on it.



I have the SA Habahir in mid-size format, it is very nicely done but takes good eyes to read the mefarshim on the daf.... but if the OP has young kids he won't have this issue
